# Soft delete cascade not working

Tags: mysql, go, go-gorm

Objective: If a User is marked deleted in a soft delete, his calendar should also be marked deleted.

**structs:**

```
type User struct {
    gorm.Model
    Username  string
    FirstName string
    LastName  string
    Calendar  Calendar
}

type Calendar struct {
    gorm.Model
    Name   string
    UserID uint
}
```

**constraint:**

```
db.Model(&Calendar{}).AddForeignKey("user_id", "users(id)", "CASCADE","CASCADE")
```

**Problem:**

*A hard delete works: Both the user and his calendar are deleted (records are gone)*

```
db.Exec("Delete from users where id=3")
```

*A soft delete does not work as anticpated:*

```
db.Where("id = ?", 3).Delete(&User{})
```

With a soft delete,

1. the user table field => deleted_at is dated.
2. the calendar table =? deleted_at is blank

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A soft delete means gorm do not remove your data. It only mark a non-zero `DeleteAt` timestamp. That is not supported by database directly. So foreign key has no effect here.

That means you need to manually implement the cascaded delete yourself, like this:

```golang
func DeleteUser(db *gorm.DB, id int) error {
  tx := db.Begin()
  if tx.Where("id = ?", id).Delete(&User{}); tx.Error != nil {
    tx.Rollback()
    return tx.Error
  }
  // Changed this line
  // if tx.Where("user_id = id", 3).Delete(&Calendar{}); tx.Error != nil {
     if tx.Where("user_id = ?", id).Delete(&Calendar{}); tx.Error != nil {
    tx.Rollback()
    return tx.Error
  }
  return tx.Commit().Error
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Gorm now has a `Delete with Select` functionality.

```
db.Select("Calender").Delete(&user)
```

Ref: [Gorm Docs](https://gorm.io/docs/associations.html#Delete-with-Select)